# Create IIS7 virtual directory programmatically

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7, virtual-directory

I can create Virtual directories in an application with this code:

```
ServerManager iisManager = new ServerManager();
Application app = iisManager.Sites["NewSite"].Applications["/Sales"];
app.VirtualDirectories.Add("/VDir", "d:\\MyVDir");
iisManager.CommitChanges();
```

But I cannot create a Virtual directory in the root of the Website.

¿Any ideas?

Answer (score 7):

The answer is this one:

```
ServerManager iisManager = new ServerManager();
Site mySite = iisManager.Sites["nameOfYourSite"];
mySite.Applications[0].VirtualDirectories.Add("/nameVirtualDirectory","VirtualDirectoryPath");
iisManager.CommitChanges();
```

Comment: Because the root of the website is the Application[0].